# peewee: filter select query results from many to many relationship

Tags: python, sql, orm, many-to-many, peewee

I have the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""doc"""

import peewee

db = peewee.SqliteDatabase(":memory:")


class BaseModel(peewee.Model):  # pylint: disable=W0232
    """base model"""

    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=C0111,W0232,R0903
        database = db


class Student(BaseModel):
    """doc"""
    name = peewee.CharField()


class Course(BaseModel):
    """doc"""
    name = peewee.CharField()


class StudentCourse(BaseModel):
    """doc"""
    student = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Student)
    course = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Course)

Student.create_table()
Course.create_table()
StudentCourse.create_table()

s1 = Student(name="Student1")
s1.save()
s2 = Student(name="Student2")
s2.save()
s3 = Student(name="Student3")
s3.save()
s4 = Student(name="Student4")
s4.save()
c1 = Course(name="course1")
c1.save()
c2 = Course(name="course2")
c2.save()
c3 = Course(name="course3")
c3.save()
sc21 = StudentCourse(student=s2, course=c1)
sc21.save()
sc22 = StudentCourse(student=s2, course=c2)
sc22.save()
sc23 = StudentCourse(student=s2, course=c3)
sc23.save()
sc31 = StudentCourse(student=s3, course=c1)
sc31.save()
sc32 = StudentCourse(student=s3, course=c2)
sc32.save()
sc41 = StudentCourse(student=s4, course=c1)
sc41.save()

query = (
    StudentCourse
    .select(StudentCourse, Student, Course)
    .join(Course)
    .switch(StudentCourse)
    .join(Student)
    .order_by(Student.name))

last = None
for student_course in query:
    student = student_course.student
    if student != last:
        last = student
        print "Student: %s" % student.name
    print "    - %s" % student_course.course.name
```

that produces this output:

```
Student: Student2
    - course1
    - course2
    - course3
Student: Student3
    - course1
    - course2
Student: Student4
    - course1
```

This is basically the example from [peewee docs](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html#implementing-many-to-many)

I need to filter the results and pick only those students who have all the courses from a given subset:

```
courses = ["course1", "course2"]
```

I have tried to use the **IN** operator and modified the select query like this:

```
    query = (
    StudentCourse
    .select(StudentCourse, Student, Course)
    .join(Course)
    .switch(StudentCourse)
    .join(Student)
    .where(Course.name << courses)
    .order_by(Student.name))
```

But it produces a wrong result, which means I'm doing it wrong:

```
Student: Student2
    - course1
    - course2
Student: Student3
    - course1
    - course2
Student: Student4
    - course1
```

There are two wrong things here:

1. **course3** for **Student2** is not printed, I need it. I assume this is because **course3** isn't in **courses** list.
2. **Student4** gets selected, but it shouldn't, because **Student4** doesn't have both **course1** and **course2**, yet **course1** is **IN** the **courses** list.

Is it possible to achieve what I want in just one query or I have to iterate over students, make a **SELECT** query for each of them and match the list of their courses against my **courses** filter?

My goal is to get this output:

```
Student: Student2
    - course1
    - course2
    - course3
Student: Student3
    - course1
    - course2
```

Answer (score -2):

This should get you pointed in the right direction: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/